# SQL Query error

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query with a problem:

```
SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`name`, `User`.`email`,
 `User`.`lastname`, `User`.`mobile_phone`, `User`.`status`,
  `Activity`.`name`, `Business`.`name`, `Activity`.`id`,
   `Business`.`id`, 
    (SELECT SUM(points) FROM ( SELECT SUM(points) as points
     FROM meetings as Meeting
      where `Meeting`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) x)
       AS `User__total_points`
```

The error is:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'User.id' in 'where clause'
```

The query is more complex but this is the part that give an error.

EDITED

new query witout sum

```
SELECT User.id, User.name, User.email, User.lastname, User.mobile_phone, User.status, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM meetings as Meeting WHERE Meeting.status = 1 and Meeting.user_id = User.id and (date BETWEEN "2016-01-01" AND "2016-02-29")) AS meetings_count
FROM bup.users AS User
```

works fine User.id  is not the problem

but if

```
SELECT User.id, User.name, User.email, User.lastname, User.mobile_phone, User.status, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM meetings as Meeting WHERE Meeting.status = 1 and Meeting.user_id = User.id and (date BETWEEN "2016-01-01" AND "2016-02-29")) AS meetings_count,
**(SELECT SUM(points) FROM ( SELECT SUM(points) as points FROM meetings as Meeting where Meeting.user_id = User.id) x) AS total_points**
FROM bup.users AS User
```

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'User.id' in 'where clause' error again

thanks

Comment: Share you DB Structure for both the tables in the question

Comment: Of course you're going to get that, you don't have a `user` table used in your query anywhere. You don't have `from user`, you don't have `join user`, or even alias establishing `user`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see it here in your code, but:

```
`User.id` -- A column literally called "User.id"
`User`.`id` -- A column called "id" in the table "User"
```

These are two different things. You'll want to look through your queries for any instance of the literal `User.id` one.

It's worth noting that if you design your schema with clean names you won't need the backticks on everything. In fact, they get in the way and cause problems like this if used without question. The only time you need them is if a column or table name has spaces, special characters, or conflicts with [MySQL reserved keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html), but these situations can be avoided with careful planning.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL will process the inner SELECT statement **FIRST** and so the inner statement will not have any knowledge of the outer statement as they're mutually exclusive.

So your inner statement is:

```
SELECT SUM(points) as points
     FROM meetings as Meeting
      where `Meeting`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`
```

Where you can (should) now clearly see the issue is that the table `User` has not been defined, so you need to correct this with something like:

```
 SELECT SUM(points) as points
     FROM meetings INNER JOIN User 
     ON `Meeting`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`
```

Which will solve your error but may not give you the precise results you need. Unfortunately I don't have a clear solution for your short of inverting your stack of SELECTs so your inner one becomes the outer one and the Outer one becomes the inner one, etc.

Hopefully someone else can edit this answer and add a better solution. But that's your issue.

Also note that `User` is a MySQL keyword and so it'll make life easier for you not to use that for column or table names. [Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html).